# Undefined is not a function error formatting date in JS

Tags: javascript, date

I got an undefiend error passing my date value into formatDate function, why? How to ceate an instance in my case?

```js
    function formatDate(date) {
        if (date) {
            var hours = date.getHours();
            var minutes = date.getMinutes();
            var format = hours < 12 ? 'am' : 'pm';
            hours = hours % 12;
            hours = hours ? hours : 12; // making 0 a 12
            minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
            var time = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + format;
            var output = date.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear() + " " + time;

            console.log(output);
          alert(output);

        }
    }
```

```html
    <input type="datetime-local" onblur="formatDate(this.value)" />
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because the date that you receive in your function is a string from your input, not a `Date` object.

So before you call something like `date.getHours();` you must need to parse your date as string to Date or you will have the `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` error.

Comment: And to parse the date as a string, you would do `new Date()`